# In MIPS32, is "add $t1 $t1 $t1" the same as "sll $t1 $t1 1"

Tags: assembly, mips, mips32

I was wondering if in MIPS 32, the two following are identical:

`add $t1 $t1 $t1`

`sll $t1 $t1 1`

Does `sll` handle a possible overflow differently than `add`? I can't seem to find a good explanation online.

Thank you!

Comment: `addu` would be the equivalent as that does not raise an exception.

Comment: In 64-bit MIPS, another difference is that 32-bit shifts sign-extend the result to 64-bit, unlike most other instructions with 32-bit operand-size.  (Not an answer since you asked about MIPS32, where 32-bit is the full register width, same as classic MIPS I / MIPS II.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you suspect correctly: `sll` won't ever trigger an overflow exception, whereas `add` will trigger overflow when interpreting the numbers as signed integers whose sum won't fit in 32-bits.

As Jester says, `addu` will also never trigger overflow so is more equivalent to your `sll`.

Most instruction sets have some duplication/overlap like this, as it would take both design & implementation effort to prevent, arguably for little or no return on investment.

We should always use `addu` for pointer arithmetic because we don't want a signed  overflow check.  Pointers are unsigned, and `addu` stands for add unsigned — but it performs the same arithmetic as `add`, just omitting overflow checking.  You might think it checks for unsigned overflow but it doesn't, so it is a bit of an oddity to call it `addu`.  We should also use `addiu` rather than `addi` with pointers for the same reason — to forgo a signed integer overflow check.  Adjustment of the stack pointer should be done with `addiu`, but you'll often see people use `addi` by mistake.

RISC V decided to remove the overflow checking entirely, so if you want an overflow check you have to use more instructions; the regular instruction is just `add` and works for both signed or unsigned integers (the additional instructions you would add to check for overflow would be specific to whether signed or unsigned).